# Can reading on a moving vehicle cause retinal detachment?

Tags: ophthalmology, reading

When I was a child, I was told that reading a book on a moving vehicle (a car or a bus) could cause the retina to detach. I always doubted that, since I could not imagine how it would happen.

Is there any truth to that statement?

Answer (score 6):

The [Mayo Clinic page on retinal detachment](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/retinal-detachment/DS00254) does not list either trains or reading as causes, and the closest it comes to reading on a vehicle for risk factors is "Previous severe eye injury or trauma", which you don't get without something bad happening to the vehicle.